# multiple robots in ROS kinetic with Gazebo 7

Tags: ros, multiple, gazebo7, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone point me to a good example of using a single URDF and instantiating multiple robots in Gazebo, and also having a consistent transform (tf2) tree?

There are several instances of questions on this forum that are old, and all refer to setting the tf_prefix, which is deprecated. (c.f. http://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/)

I have tried several variations of changes to name space, that will get me the robots spawning correctly in Gazebo, and topics named correctly, but the tf tree is not consistent with I view the robot model in RVIz.

I am specifically interested in the turtlebot models, but any consistent set of URDF and launch files should be sufficient to point me in the right direction with the new setup.

Or if someone can point me to an up to date tutorial I would appreciate it.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250405/multiple-robots-in-ros-kinetic-with-gazebo-7/) by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on ROS Answers with karma: 476 on 2016-12-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

`tf_prefix` may be deprecated, but is afaik really the only way to get TF working with multiple robots.

As to an example, I believe the one Clearpath did is still a nice one: [Simulating Multiple Husky UGVs in Gazebo](https://www.clearpathrobotics.com/2016/03/simulating-multiple-husky-ugvs-in-gazebo).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dcconner](https://answers.ros.org/users/3396/dcconner/) on 2016-12-20**:
That worked for me.   I would be interested to hear from OSRF folks about their planned roadmap for handling this with tf_prefix supposedly being deprecated.